# Generate UPC Barcode with Number with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

I'm able to generate barcode by using "Barby" gem with "EAN13 & UPCA" But I need to show numbers with the barcode and I have no idea, what I'm missing in code.

Current Generated Barcode

[image]

Read out the barby gem documentation but no luck.

```
  @barcode_value = "123456789123"  
  full_path = "public/Barcodes/"+@barcode_value+".png"
  barcode = Barby::EAN13.new(@barcode_value)
  File.open(full_path, 'wb') { |f| f.write barcode.to_png(:margin => 3, :xdim => 2, :height => 50) }
```

Generate Barcode with Number.

Required Barcode

[image]

Comment: Currently there are no ruby gems which support your request.

Comment: @Bijendra  so, is there any alternative solution or method to generate this type of barcode?

Comment: is there any update on this? I am also looking for the same and not able to find anything working.

Comment: I am also looking for this issue any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you generated is a Code 39. The barcode you marked as required is a Code EAN 13, not UPC (those are not identical). One way to create such a code with Ruby would be using an API, e.g. https://mcapi.io/barcode/barcode-api-ruby.php

The API is hosted on RapidAPI; sample call to create your barcode:

```
# Ruby
  
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = URI("https://mcapi-barcode.p.rapidapi.com/")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
request["x-rapidapi-key"] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
request["x-rapidapi-host"] = 'mcapi-barcode.p.rapidapi.com'
request.body = "{
    \"data\": \"9501101530003\",
    \"type\": 1,
    \"size\": 2,
    \"format\": \"pdf\"
}"

response = http.request(request)
```

The returned code will be in response.read_body as a base64 encoded PDF (posted as a screenshot since SO doesn't display PDFs):

[EAN13 created with Ruby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM50H.png)

(Disclaimer: We are the developers.)

Comment: Sadly, the domain doesn't resolve for me.  Looks like it's gone?